# Convert XML based configuration to Annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring, annotations, metadata

Is there any Utility available to convert XML based config files (say in Spring or Hibernate) to Annotations? If not would it be worthwhile to build such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following page

```
https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/ant.html
```

And see item 4.4.2.

POJO java code exporter (<hbm2java>)

It says:

> <hbm2java> is a java codegenerator. Options for controlling wether JDK 5 syntax can be used and **whether the POJO should be annotated with EJB3/Hibernate Annotations**.

```
<hibernatetool destdir="${build.dir}/generated">
    <configuration configurationfile="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true"/>
</hibernatetool>
```

About ejb3 attribute, it says:

> Code will contain EJB 3 features, e.g. using annotations from javax.persistence and org.hibernate.annotations

Comment: I don't think that's what Debu is asking. He wans to generate annotations on entities that would produce Hibernate configuration equivalent to the XML-based one he has. I strongly doubt SchemaExport can do that; but if it can I'd appreciate if you've pointed me out to a doc describing the process.

Comment: @ChssPly76 You are right, Chss, I think Hibernate Tools is the only way to do it. UPvote to you. Thank you!